# Can't deploy Flask application to Google App Engine with web3 library

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web3py

If I include the line `from web3 import Web3` and deploy my flask server to app engine it says deploy successful, but when I open the page in browser I get the error: 502 bad gateway (nginx).

If I run it locally everything works fine.

Why could this be happening?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: do you have it in your requirements.txt file?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Ah, thank you! It solved it. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it wasn't installed in production(it works in local environment because it's installed in your local environment).

You need to include it in your `requirements.txt` file and then Google will install it when your App is first started